# Can you pause, disable a Github Action?

Tags: github, github-actions

Is there a way to put an argument into a GitHub action definition so that the action does not run when you push it to GitHub?

I have a package template, and I want to include certain actions, but I don't want users of the template to have to do something to get those actions to run (not run automatically – and fail – when when they push to GitHub)

I'm hoping there's a configuration field for `run_automatically: false` or something similar.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. If you don't want a Github Action workflow to run on push, don't you just have to remove the push option from the trigger list? 

Comment: Duh. You understood, I was just missing how obvious it was. Smh. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

There are two ways:

1. One you can disable it using the [Github's actions tab](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/disabling-and-enabling-a-workflow)
2. Add the following code to the workflow

```
...
jobs:
 build_and_preview:
   if: ${{ false }} # <- This make sure the workflow is skipped without any alert
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   .
   .
```

Comment: YAML comments should be done with pound sign and not double forward slash as in JS. :P

Comment: One can do just `if: false` instead :)